# Singular point at Neumann Boundary Condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, laplacian, singularity

I am trying to solve the following Boundary Value Problem - a particle is moving on the surface of a sphere:

$$
\triangle y(\theta)=\frac{d²y(\theta)}{d \theta²} + \cot{\theta } \frac{dy(\theta)}{d\theta} = -1
$$

where $\triangle$ is the laplacian in spherical coordinates, with the BC $y(\theta_0) =  0$ and $y'(\pi) = 0$.

I found a solution to the homogeneous equation:

$$
y(\theta)_H = A_1 \ln \Big(\frac{\cos {\theta/2}}{\sin{\theta/2}} \Big) + A_2.
$$

However, $\theta = \pi$ is a singular point; $\theta = 0$ is not within the domain so I don't have to worry about it.

I don't know how I should apply the boundary conditions. Is the homogenous solution I found valid? How should I deal with the $\theta = \pi$ point? Should I expect $y(\theta)_H$ to be trivially zero and try find a particular solution instead? I would really appreciate any suggestion on what to try next!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it helps, but:

$y''+y'\cot\theta=-1\\
y''\sin\theta+y'\cos\theta=-\sin\theta\\
(y'\sin\theta)'=-\sin\theta\\
y'\sin\theta=\cos\theta+C\\
y'=\dfrac{C+\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\\
$

For $C=1$ we get $\lim\limits_{\theta\to\pi}\dfrac{1+\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=0=y'(\pi)$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved my problem! :)